# Reproject Raster from xmin=0 to x=-180

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, reprojection-error

I am working with NOAA Files: https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.cpc.globaltemp.html

They have the projection EPSG:9001.

```
> extent(raster.nc)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 0 
xmax       : 360 
ymin       : -90 
ymax       : 90
```

So the central point is somewhere in the Pacific. All other files I work with are EPSG:4326, like Shapefiles of the World: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esri::world-countries-generalized

```
extent(world.shape)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -180 
xmax       : 180 
ymin       : -89 
ymax       : 83.6236
```

I cannot seem to get those two together.

```
projectRaster(raster.nc, crs=CRS(projection(world.shape)),method = "bilinear")
```

leads to

```
Error in if (yn == yx) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In `dim<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(nr, nc)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

(also if I do not use `CRS()`)

How can I solve this problem? I would like to work with EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `terra::rotate` (or its outdated "raster" equivalent)

Some example data

```
library(terra)
url <- "https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_temp/tmax.1979.nc"
f <- basename(url)
download.file(url, f, mode="wb")
x <- rast(f)
```

Solution

```
y <- rotate(x)
```

Illustration

```
ext(x)
#SpatExtent : 0, 360, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
ext(y)
#SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

plot(y, 1)
```